# Idiomatic Go for abstracting resource allocation/deallocation

Tags: error-handling, go, resources, idioms

Is there an idiomatic Go way for abstracting resource allocation/deallocation? My initial guess is to abstract the allocation/deallocation in a higher-order function:

```
func withResource(f func(Resource)error) error {
    // allocate resource
    // defer free resource
    return f(resource)
}
```

However, this line of thinking is borrowed directly from the functional paradigm and doesn't seem to align well with Go's largely imperative nature.

As a concrete example, running a daemon for the duration of a block of code is a recurring theme in my current project, so I've created a `withDaemon` function to abstract the commonality:

```
func withDaemon(
    cmd *exec.Cmd,
    f func(io.ReadCloser, io.ReadCloser, io.WriteCloser) error,
) error {
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("couldn't get stdout: %v", err)
    }

    stderr, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("couldn't get stderr: %v", err)
    }

    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("couldn't get stdin: %v", err)
    }

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to start: %v", err)
    }

    defer func() {
        cmd.Process.Kill()
        cmd.Wait()
    }

    return f(stdout, stderr, stdin)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the idiomatic way would be to create a Daemon type, and to just use defer in the caller:

```
d := NewDaemon(...)
defer d.Stop()
doWhatever()
```